# Limit x-axis in Apexcharts.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, apexcharts

I want to limit the x-axis in the bar graph I'm using, I have multiple values but I want to show only 7 and then the user can scroll to see the remaining. Does this option exist?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the value of the `xaxis.range` property should help.

```
var options = {
    series: [
        {
            name: 'PRODUCT A',
            data: [44, 55, 41, 67, 22, 43, 13, 23, 20, 8, 13, 27]
        }, {
            name: 'PRODUCT B',
            data: [13, 23, 20, 8, 13, 27, 11, 17, 15, 15, 21, 14]
        }, {
            name: 'PRODUCT C',
            data: [11, 17, 15, 15, 21, 14, 44, 55, 41, 67, 22, 43]
        }
    ],
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 350,
        stacked: true,
        toolbar: {
          show: true
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        range: 7
    }
};
var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

Comment: You're welcome! [Here](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/) is more information just in case